# How to filter/sort an array of objects based on a single object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, object

I'm new to React.js, and am looking for a quick and easy way to filter and sort some user data for a website that I'm building.  Basically, I'm trying to find a way to sort an array of objects based on a single object property in React.js (using hooks).

I have an array of users called `tutors`.  It's setup like this: `const [tutors, setTutors] = useState<tutor[]>(null);`  It contains multiple instances of the `tutor` object, which has the following properties:

```
export interface tutor {
  lock: boolean,
  nonce: string,
  id: string,
  first_name: string,
  last_name: string,
  bio: string,
  contact_info: any,
  setup_intent: string,
  profile_pic: string,
  default_schedule: any,
  timezone_offset: string,
  education: { school: string, degree: string }[],
  subjects: string[],
  price: number,
  zoom_link: string,
  viewed: []
};
```

My goal is to sort `tutors` based on user ID (as indicated by `id`), so that objects with the desired user IDs are pushed to the start of the `tutors` array.  I can then return this nely sorted array.  I have the list of user IDs that I want to keep already stored in an array of strings called `pinTutor`.  Somehow, I would like to sort the array of objects `tutors` based on the array of strings `pinTutor`.  However, I'm having some difficulty accomplishing this.  Here's some things I've tried so far:

```
let arrTutors = tutors;

// Function for storing/transferring some data
function Tutor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.props = "";
}

// now we have tutors with IDs from "0" to "tutors.length"
for (let i = 0; i < tutors.length; i++) {
    arrTutors.push(new Tutor(i.toString()));
}

//function for sorting by pins
function sortByStar(arr){ 

    //Array for storing filtered object of arrays with userIDs from pinTutor
    let filteredtutors = []

    //Filtering
    pinTutor.forEach((tutorID) => {
        filteredtutors = arr.push(arrTutors.find(tutor => tutor.id === tutorID));
    });

    //Array for storing sorted object of arrays with userIDs from pinTutor at the start
    let sortedtutors = [];

    //Sorting
    for (let k = 0; k < tutors.length; k++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < filteredtutors.length; j++){
            if (filteredtutors[j]===tutors[k].id){
                sortedtutors = tutors.sort();
            }
        }
    }

    return sortedtutors;
}
```

I'm having trouble sorting my array at the end based on the IDs.  Any advice on how to implement?

Comment: Do you happen to know about [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)? It has nothing to do with React and hooks specifically, though may help to solve your problem, like `const sortedTutors = [...tutors].sort(({id:a}, {id:b}) => a-b)`

Comment: I'm aware of that method, but wasn't sure how I to use it to sort with specific user IDs.  I'm definitely trying something along those lines though, yes

Answer (score 1):

If the `id` property is a string, and you want to sort the array based on the ids  [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) order, you can use:

```js
arr.sort((a,b) => (a.id.localeCompare(b.id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the 'id' property is number even if it's string data type. This should work for you:

```
arr.sort((a,b) => (+a.id - +b.id));
```

For 'id' as alphanumeric string, use the below code:

```
arr.sort((a,b) => (+ascii(a.id) - +ascii(b.id))); 

function ascii (str: string)  {
    str = str.toUpperCase();
    let ret : string = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        ret += str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Do note that the max number value of Number datatype in typescript is "9007194749250991", so this will not work for strings larger than 8 characters.

Comment: It's a combination of numbers and letters, i.e. "5b1ty21f".  Is there any way to sort with IDs like that?

Comment: @Alex Ross, Edited the response above as per your query.